# Question on Douglas, Banach Algebra, Hardy spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, hardy-spaces

In the text by Douglas, Banach Algebra techniques in Operator Theory,  pg. 25, **1.47 Hardy spaces** was introduced.

If $\mathbb {T}$ denotes the unit circle in the complex plane, let $\chi_n $ denote the function defined on $\mathbb {T}$ by $\chi_n (z) = z^n$. The set $$H^{\infty}=\{\psi \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb {T}): \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi \chi_n dt=0\text { for n=1,2,3,..., } \} $$
is a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb {T})$. Moreover in this case, $H^{\infty}=\{\psi \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb {T}): \frac {1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi \chi_n dt=0\text { for n=1,2,3,..., } \} $ is the null space of the $w^*$-continuous function 
$$\hat\chi_n (\psi)=\frac {1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \psi \chi_n dt $$
and hence is $w^*$-closed.

My questions are:

1. I am very new to $w^*$-continuity, how can one show that the function $\hat\chi_n$ is $w^*$-continuous.
2. What is the relevance of the last statement. Can one directly use the last argument to conclude that the set $H^\infty$ is  a closed subspace of $L^\infty$?. That is does $w^*$-closeness imply closeness.

Comment: If you don't define $\chi_n$, your space is undefined. Furthermore, $\hat\chi_n$ is not a function. It's a value. What you mean is the functional $\hat\chi_n(\psi) = \int_0^{2\pi}\psi\chi_n\,dt$. And $H^\infty$ is _not_ the null space of that single functional. It's the intersection of all these null spaces.

Comment: For the closedness of $H^\infty$ in $L^\infty$ you don't need weak star. Define $F_n : L^\infty\to\mathbb C$ by $F_n(\psi) := \tfrac 1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\psi(t)e^{int}\,dt$ (I guess that $\chi_n(t) = e^{int}$). Then $|F_n(\psi)|\le\|\psi\|_\infty$, so each $F_n$ is a continous linear functional on $L^\infty$. Hence, $H^\infty = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\ker F_n$ is closed in $L^\infty$. But this does not imply the weak star-closedness.

Comment: @amsmath I've just edited

Comment: You integrate over $[0,2\pi]$. So I doubt that $\chi_n(z) = z^n$. Why do I have to tell you how to ask your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and denote by $X'$ its (topological) dual. For $x\in X$ define the linear functional $F_x : X'\to\mathbb K$ by $F_x(x') := x'(x)$. The weak star topology on $X'$ is the smallest topology on $X'$ such each $F_x$ is continuous.

Here, you have $X = L^1(\mathbb T)$ and hence $X' = L^\infty(\mathbb T)$ in the sense that the map $L^\infty\to X'$, defined by $y\mapsto\left(x\in L^1\mapsto\int_{\mathbb T}xy\,dt\right)$ is an isometric isomorphism. Hence, for $x\in L^1$ you have $F_x(y) = \int xy\,dt$, $y\in L^\infty$. If you put $x_n = e^{int}$, your functional $\hat\chi_n$ exactly equals $F_{x_n}$ and is thus weak star-continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I'll revise and let you know if I have any probs.

Comment: Your conclusion was swift. Pls, I don't  understand how you concluded that $F_{x_n}$ is weak star continuous

Comment: @stackuser Really not? Read it again. It's trivial.